# Javascript - making form inputs appear needed through key input

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that has five text inputs, a through e. I set it though so only the first two are visible through the css:display, and I set the last three to display:none initially.

I have my javascript so that it sets the last input to 'b', and the next input to 'c', and depending on whether the other texts are empty or not changes the last and next variables.

option-a, option-b, etc. is the id of the text box in the form
answer_answera, answer_answerb, etc. is the class of the form input

```
<script>
  var last = 'b';
  var next = 'c';

  if (document.getElementById('option-c').value != null) {
    last = 'c';
    next = 'd';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('option-d').value != null) {
    last = 'd';
    next = 'e';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('option-e').value != null) {
    last = '';
    next = '';
  }

  $('#answer_answer'+last).keyup(function() {
    console.log('beg');
    var elem = document.getElementById('option-'+next);
    elem.style.display="block";
    console.log('hit this');
  })
  </script>
```

This works for the first input. When I type in form input b, form input c appears. However, how do I get this to continually, I suppose, refresh itself, as form input d does not appear when I type in form input c. I thought about putting a while loop around the entire last block/keyup function, but it made the entire app slow and wouldn't load properly.

Thanks for any thoughts! :)

Comment: Are you trapping the keyboard events for the elements in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we go into solving this problem, let's quickly review some Javascript concepts. When your document first loads, everything inside the `<script></script>` tags will execute once. This means that the following statements will all be evaluated:

```
  var last = 'b';
  var next = 'c';

  if (document.getElementById('option-c').value != null) {
    last = 'c';
    next = 'd';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('option-d').value != null) {
    last = 'd';
    next = 'e';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('option-e').value != null) {
    last = '';
    next = '';
  }
```

Once they are evaluated, they will never be run again until you refresh the page. Thus, when the page is done loading `last = 'b'` and `next = 'c'` and the three `if` statements all evaluate to false and are not executed (I assume the text fields are empty on initial load). The following code will also be executed once:

```
$('#answer_answer'+last).keyup(function() {
    console.log('beg');
    var elem = document.getElementById('option-'+next);
    elem.style.display="block";
    console.log('hit this');
  })
```

However, this code binds a 'handler' (a future promise) to execute some code given a user action.

- The action is a `keyup` event on the `'#answer_answer'+last` element.
  Because we know that `last = 'b'` when this promise is made, this
  really means `'#answer_answerb'`
- The promise is to execute the following code:

  console.log('beg');
   var elem = document.getElementById('option-'+next);
   elem.style.display="block";
   console.log('hit this');

Thus, when you begin typing in `#answer_answerb` the `#answer_answerc` field is displayed (remember that `next = 'c'`). And if you type some more into `#answer_answerb` the `#answer_answerc` field remains visible. And now we know everything that your code does.

So, how do we fix it? Can you guess? We can make more promises. The full code:

```
<script>
      $('#answer_answerb).keyup(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('option-c');
        elem.style.display="block";
      })
      $('#answer_answerc).keyup(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('option-d');
        elem.style.display="block";
      })
      $('#answer_answerd).keyup(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('option-e');
        elem.style.display="block";
      })
</script>
```

This will have the desired effect, but is hard to maintain. If you decide to add more text fields, you will have to create a promise for each one. You can find a more elegant solution to your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/GkT2g/

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This answer was so thorough and thoughtful. I really appreciate your time slash help. :) It worked perfectly!

Comment: happy to help. you're on your way to being a javascript ninja!